# Overhead of loading Angular.js many times on site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I have a website which has many pages that are not exactly the same, but one thing they have in common is that on each page there are some tabs, and if you click TAB A, certain information shows up, then if you click TAB B, other information, etc.

I know that it is very easy to use Angular to do this, and I wish to use it, however I do not wish to convert the entire site to a full Angular application. I simply want to include the Angular javascript file on every page of the site, and only use the ng-hide and ng-show functionality for these tab items.

So my question is: Will it affect a user's experience much if every page he goes to on my site has to launch Angular again? I am not worried much about the network times of downloading Angular.js because I am sure I can configure caching so that the actual script doesn't have to reload, but what I am considering is the CPU/memory aspect and whether it will result in an extra period of time for every page to load - this is already an issue on this site, so adding an extra 0.5 seconds (let's say) would be undesirable.

Comment: If load times are already an issue you probably already have library scripts being loaded that could do simple hide/show, or do it with native js. Adding a whole framework for such a simple feature set seems like overkill

Comment: Furthermore, this is really easy to do even with vanilla Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy here tested something like starting up [many angular applications at once](http://jsperf.com/angularjs-boot-time)

[This buddy](https://medium.com/@_zaknelson/minimizing-initialization-time-in-angularjs-f8ae57e2cec3) conclude that caching can be pretty expensive if you decide to preload everything.

My personal and empirical opinion, if you started with something, it might be the case for you to stick with it and try to solve your problems with what your current framework offers. As you said, you don't need anything very angular-specific, it is just a couple of things.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you not using a entire framework in case you want just a simple functionality from this, keep it simple and easy.